# Getting the output metrics from Detectron2's COCOEvaluator

Tags: pytorch

The metrics from standard out are much more useful than the outputs written in the output folder.

`Standard out`

[image]

`metrics.json` and `coco_instances_results.json`

[image]

```
def test(instance, cfg, trainer, test_instance):  
  cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS = os.path.join(cfg.OUTPUT_DIR, "model_final.pth")
  cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.SCORE_THRESH_TEST = 0.7   # TODO What is this
  cfg.DATASETS.TEST = (test_instance, )
  predictor = DefaultPredictor(cfg)
  evaluator = COCOEvaluator(test_instance, cfg, False, output_dir=cfg.OUTPUT_DIR)
  val_loader = build_detection_test_loader(cfg, test_instance)
  result = inference_on_dataset(trainer.model, val_loader, evaluator)
```

How can I get the details like the Average Percision for ioU=0.5 or per-category bbox AP?

Comment: Can you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1**

For the case of using detectron2's `COCOEvaluator` where the argument `max_dets_per_image` is set (I think greater than 100) to values that trigger the use of class `COCOevalMaxDets`, you can modify `coco_evaluation.py` to grab the `str` being generation in `COCOevalMaxDets._summarize` method and use as you need (e.g. save to a file).  In the current implementation of `COCOevalMaxDets._summarize` the info you asked about is being printed by `print(iStr.format(titleStr, typeStr, iouStr, areaRng, maxDets, mean_s)`

**Case 2**

For the case of using detectron2's `COCOEvaluator` where the argument `max_dets_per_image` is set such that `COCOevalMaxDets` is not being used, I think either `COCOeval_opt` or `COCOeval` is being used as you will see the following line in `_evaluate_predictions_on_coco` method in `coco_evaluation.py`:

```
eval = (COCOeval_opt if use_fast_impl else COCOeval)(coco_gt, coco_dt, iou_type)
```

Thus, you would need to look into `COCOeval_opt` or `COCOeval`, find the lines with the info, and manipulate as you need.
Note, `COCOeval_opt` is in `detectron2.evaluation.fast_eval_api` and `COCOeval` is in `pycocotools.cocoeval`

**Note**

If you don't want to say modify `coco_evaluation.py` you could create your own `custom_evaluation.py` starting with a copy of `coco_evaluation.py` but changing method names and modifying to get what you need.  This is probably a better method b/c it will keep the `detectron2` code unchanged.

Here is the source code on github [coco_evaluation.py](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/blob/main/detectron2/evaluation/coco_evaluation.py)